# Azure AD B2C Audit Logs - Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to retrieve the Azure AD B2C users sign-in audit logs, but its throw below error

```
    var signIns = await _graphClient.AuditLogs.SignIns
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();
```

fail:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Status Code: Forbidden
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Authentication_RequestFromNonPremiumTenantOrB2CTenant
Message: **Neither tenant is B2C or tenant doesn't have premium license**

---

Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2020-10-05T10:12:34
request-id: 1740dcc7-3ffd-4d81-a721-a18e3fee0e1a
client-request-id: 1740dcc7-3ffd-4d81-a721-a18e3fee0e1a
ClientRequestId: 1740dcc7-3ffd-4d81-a721-a18e3fee0e1a

at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
at Microsoft.Graph.AuditLogRootSignInsCollectionRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken).

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Based on the error message it states that  your tenant is not licensed with an [Azure AD P1 license](https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/troubleshoot-graph-api#error-neither-tenant-is-b2c-or-tenant-doesnt-have-premium-license). Can you make sure your tenant is having Azure AD P1 License

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is accessing sign-in reports requires an Azure Active Directory premium 1 (P1) license.

Check it in [Azure Portal Licenses](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Licenses).

[image]

Comment: Really hate how Microsoft moves basic security information to a premium subscription.