# Azure Sign In data not available via REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft had made **free** for the **Azure Sign In Report**. I could see those reports in the Azure AD portal. **But couldn't retrieve the data via REST API**

The following site also not pointing that this API requires any Premium license.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

But on testing with my tenant, I have got the following error code

**Request**: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns

[Response of the Azure Sign In Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdF0G.png)

**Message**: Neither tenant is B2C or tenant doesn't have a premium license
Why Microsoft is not providing data for these tenants? Are there any other ways to retrieve the data from these tenants?

Answer (score 0):

> Neither tenant is B2C or tenant doesn't have premium license

Accessing sign-in reports requires an Azure Active Directory premium 1 (P1) license. If you see this error message while accessing sign-ins, make sure that your tenant is licensed with an **Azure AD P1 license**.

see: [error report](https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/troubleshoot-graph-api#error-neither-tenant-is-b2c-or-tenant-doesnt-have-premium-license).

---

**Update:**

I used a simple method to reproduce your problem. I used an account without a p1 license to call the api and it reported the same error as you:

[image]

Then I assigned a p1 license to the account. The api call will succeed:

[image]

This is a problem with MS, it is not detailed in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You refereed an old document (updated in 2018), but MS made the sign-in reports in Azure AD Basic itself in Feb 2020. (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-auth-and-exchange-online-february-2020-update/ba-p/1191282)

Also, other API documentation has a clear mention of the required license. For example, Risk detection API clearly states that it requires P1/P2(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/riskdetection-list?view=graph-rest-1.0).

So this looks like an issue on the Microsoft side.

Comment: @Maerona_Wynn  Please see my answer update.

Comment: Thanks for taking a step ahead to test the issue. This behavior existed even at the time MS enforced Premium license to see sign-in data. For example, earlier we can assign a single P1/P2 license to see the premium data in the portal and the same data can be retrieved via API too.

But MS now made the sign-in data available in Azure AD Basic itself. We could see the report data in the AAD portal without any AAD Premium license. But API still has the licensing restriction in the API documentation, there is no licensing relation information.

Comment: @Maerona_Wynn  This api call does require a p1 license, do you log in with a user with a p1 license and then call this api for testing?

Comment: No. I am testing with Azure AD Basic License. I'm asking there is no proper license- related info in the documentation. So MS might made mistake to take away this license restriction

Comment: @Maerona_Wynn  I have the same idea as you, MS documents should be more rigorous, and you can also make your suggestions to Microsoft. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Comment: @Maerona_Wynn  Can you accept it as an answer? ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) Thanks!

Comment: @Maerona_Wynn  Hi,Have you encountered a new problem?

Comment: We are expecting "Removal of License Constraint for the API as per said in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins#what-azure-ad-license-do-you-need-to-access-sign-in-activity" from the Microsoft side.

Comment: @Maerona_Wynn   Unfortunately, this is currently impossible. To access the login report, we must have a premium (P1) license. I talked about this with Microsoft personnel and got a positive answer.

Comment: @Maerona_Wynn  For similar questions, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64207326/azure-ad-b2c-audit-logs-graph-api

Comment: Can I know what the Microsoft Personnel has replied ?

Comment: @Maerona_Wynn   Sorry, my reply is a bit late, and Microsoft replied:  Storage of data is costly, so you must purchase a premium license to enjoy the service, which is not free.

Comment: This is not a positive reply as they are pointing out that the data will not be available in the API which makes the statement fake"The sign-in activity report is available in all editions of Azure AD and can also be accessed through the Microsoft Graph API" as mentioned in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins#what-azure-ad-license-do-you-need-to-access-sign-in-activity