# Azure AD B2C - Audit log / Sign in Log Adding additional fields

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to add a device id (hash) to be added part of the sign in logs so I know the request has originated from a particular device . Can I get my hands on an azure AD B2C sample on how to push the device id (hash) to be part of the sign in logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot add additional fields to the sign-in log because it's read-only.

And I don't know why you need to put a device id into sign-in log. It has been there. See [deviceDetail resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/devicedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0).

> **deviceId**  String  Refers to the UniqueID of the device used for signing
> in.

To get it you can call [Microsoft graph List signIns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns
```

Calling this API doesn't require B2C authentication. Just implement it in C# by following [this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request).

Comment: Is there any configuration to log the device id ?   I generally see the device id not populated  IE - "deviceId": "{PII Removed}"

Comment: @srini Did your device join into AAD?

Comment: This is the query I used - GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns.    This is the output I am seeing  "deviceDetail": {
                "deviceId": "",
                "displayName": "",}  How will I join into AAD?  I can however get the OS version.

Comment: @srini You should join your device into AAD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-join-device-on-network. Then AAD can log the device id for you. As I mentioned before, we cannot customize the device id in to the sign-in logs.

Comment: This appears to be a AD feature rather than azure AD B2C.  Let me know if this will work for azure adb2c

Comment: @srini It will work for B2C when you have an Azure Active Directory premium 1 (P1) license. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64207326/azure-ad-b2c-audit-logs-graph-api?answertab=votes#tab-top.

Comment: I have P1 so the api is working.  This link more like a pure azure  AD rather than B2C https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-join-device-on-network.  It describes on adding devices to the PC.  Our app is a mobile app.

Comment: @srini You can use Authenticator App or use Microsoft Company Portal. See this answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/87736/azure-ad%E3%81%B8ios-%E3%83%86%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95.html. Android is the same as IOS.

Comment: For end customers we do not see the authenticator app that popular.  So it is not an option.

Comment: @srini If so, you can consider using Microsoft Company Portal, which is relatively more complicated.

Comment: This appears to be azure ad link are you sure it will work on azure adb2c .  Do you have a link to the microsoft company portal ? Is this for B2B users ?

Comment: @srini I haven't tried it to see if it works for B2B user. But for B2C, it should work. the links here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/android-enroll and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/ios-enroll.